# Can't remove Google maps autocomplete library scripts from page on UnMount in React App

Tags: javascript, google-maps, reactjs, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete

I'm using google maps autocomplete within a React app, But I am getting error at componentwillUnmount Lifecycle event that :

> this.autocomplete.removeListener is not a function

and when I come back to the component I get the following error:

> You have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page.
>   This may cause unexpected errors.

Upon checking the page elements using devtools, it seems that multiple scripts tags containing https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/* 
are added to the head of the html page.

If I comment out the `this.autocomplete.removeListener('place_changed')` in the ComponentWillUnmount the script tag from the body gets removed but all the head script tags remain. And if I uncomment the same line then the even the body script tag I appended on component mount lifecycle remains and a new one gets created.

```
 componentDidMount () {
    this.script = document.createElement('script')
    this.script.src = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=${googleMapsAPIKey}&libraries=places`
    this.script.async = 1
    this.script.defer = 1
    this.script.onload = () => this.initAutocomplete()
    this.script.onerror = () => this.initAuthcompleteFailed()

    document.body.appendChild(this.script)
  }

  componentWillUnmount () {
    this.autocomplete.removeListener('place_changed')
    // google.maps.event.clearInstanceListeners(this.autocomplete)
    // console.log('THIS SCRIPT: ', this.script)
    document.body.removeChild(this.script)
  }

  initAutocomplete () {
    console.log('Google Maps Loaded')
    this.autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(this._input.input, {types: ['geocode']})
    this.autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', this.handlePlaceChanged)
    this.geolocate()
  }

  initAuthcompleteFailed () {
      console.log('Google Maps Loadeding Error')
  }
```

Comment: Error *"You have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors."* occurs if your web page includes maps api more than one time. Please check if there was a .js file that was also calling maps api. You can check this [sample code](https://github.com/FaridSafi/react-native-google-places-autocomplete) on GitHub and this related [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38040656/google-places-autocomplete-inside-a-react-component).